# Какая практическая польза от контекстов?

Tags: javascript

Как человек, который работал в основном с языками с ООП языками со статической типизацией, мне не совсем ясно какую практическую пользу несут все эти заморочки с контекстами в JavaScript.

Во многих учебных пособиях говорится

> вы можете вызвать функцию в контексте другого объекта, что ему будет
>   доступна вся подноготная объекта

и приводится какой-нибудь forEach, где для перечисления нужно иметь всего ничего.

Однако, если заглянуть в статью [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), то нигде нету описания, что он под капотом использует. Наверное, можно где-то найти исходники и посмотреть, что нужно использовать для итерирования, однако, разве это не копание в грязном белье реализации?

В других ЯП это находится на поверхности в виде интерфейсов каких-нибудь.

Ну и еще мне не понятно то, почему все танцы с потерей контекста и т п- это поведение по умолчанию и если мне нужно, что бы коллбек нормально отработал, то я должен использовать биндинг к контексту.

Comment: Данный язык использует другую парадигму программирования. Ни один язык не обязан следовать каким либо другим языкам в той или иной мере. Вопрос "почему так сделано, если у других не так" не имеет смысла.

Comment: Что касается forEach - это просто удобный метод перечисления свойств. в другом языке вы на его месте бы использовали обычный `for(...;...;...)`. Про "под капотом", не понял что вы имели ввиду. Но замечу, что в языках о которых вы говорите, просто нет встроенных типов данных, хоть как то похожих на объекты JS. Соответственно нет и аналогов forEach

Comment: Алгоритм работы `forEach` из `Array.prototype` описан [в спецификации](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/9.0/#sec-array.prototype.foreach). Там же в спецификации указано, следующее: _The forEach function is **intentionally generic**; it does not require that its this value be an Array object. Therefore it can be transferred to other kinds of objects for use as a method._

Comment: @Mike у каждой парадигмы есть свои + и -. Какие + у подхода, который был выбран в JS? Имхо, какой-нибудь традиционных подход был бы не чем не хуже.

Comment: @Zabuza Он дает необычайную гибкость, которая на "традиционных ООП языках" недостижима, без применения всяких очень сложных технологий вроде рефлексии. А вообще просто попишите на нем что нибудь боле менее серьезное и скажите лично для вас это плюсы или минусы. Никто вам не может перечислить плюсов, просто потому, что мышление у всех людей разное и то что для одного это плюс, для другого минус

Comment: На вопрос где сравнивается ООП и объектная модель JS как будто это _разные_ вещи, в принципе не может быть ответа - так как вопрос некорректен, и сам собой отпадает если хоть немножко изучить матчасть.